# Determine asymptotic growth rate from plot

Tags: plot, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

im trying to determine the asymptotic growth rate for the plot below, which has a logarithmic x-axis (base 2) and linear y-axis. It seems sub-logarithmic to me, but what how would one exactly determine the rate (in the big-O notation of asymptotic complexity)?[image: original plot]
original plot above,in the one below the blue line is sqrt(), green log() and the last one the original function

[image: the blue line is now sqrt(), green log() and the last one the original function]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the assumption you can exhibit a constant number `c` such that `f(2^(i+1))/f(2^i)) = c` for every integer `i`, you can consider the fact that

```
f(2^i) = c.f(2^(i-1)) = c^i.f(1)
```

So for any integer k,

```
f(k) = f(2^log2(k))
     = c^log2(k).f(1)
     = k^log2(c).f(1)
```

I tried to estimate few values of the ratio `f(2^(i+1)) / f(2^i)`:

```
f(2^12) / f(2^11) ~= 0.250 / 0.175 ~= 1.43
f(2^11) / f(2^10) ~= 0.175 / 0.125 ~= 1.4
f(2^10) / f(2^9)  ~= 0.125 / 0.085 ~= 1.47
f(2^9)  / f(2^8)  ~= 0.085 / 0.070 ~= 1.21
```

And it becomes too hard to read the values of the function for lower values of `x`.

It is not clear to me whether you truly have a constant ratio `f(2^(i+1))/f(2^i)` (you probably need more data for `x > 2^13`), but, as an example, if you chose to adopt the value of `c = 1.4`, you'd end up with the function `f(k)/f(1) ~= k^0.49 ~= sqrt(k)`, i.e. `1/f(1).f` would be "close" to the *square root* function.

**Disclaimer:**
Please take "close" here with extra care, as asymptotically, `x^(0.5 +/- epsilon`) for `epsilon > 0` is nothing but far remote from `sqrt(x)` (I mean - the difference between both functions can be made arbitrarily large as `x -> +Inf`).

Comment: great, thanks a lot! also edited my original post since i got another plot, where the blue graph is sqrt(), green log() and the lowest one the original function

Comment: So if you multiply the original function by a factor to put it on the same scale as the `sqrt` - can you see if both curves match? For instance, the `sqrt` plot shows `y ~= 63` at `x=2^11` and the original function has the value `y ~= 0.175 ~= 0.180` at the same `x` - what if you try to multiply the original function by `63/0.175 ~= 360`? (You can try different coefficients in the range `300-400`)